# отладчик Visual studio 2013 не читает содержимое файла при отладке программы

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, отладка, visual-studio-2013

Добрый вечер,

Есть функция, которая читает содержимое текстового файла:

```
void readFromFile()
{
    fstream f("knapsack_items.txt", ios::in);
    int itemcount;  Items p;
    f >> itemcount;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemcount; i++)
    {
        f >> p.price >> p.weight;
        item.push_back(p);
    }
    f.close();
};
```

После выполнения действия: **f >> itemcount;** в режиме отладки (Local Windows Debugger) в переменную **itemcount** значение из файла не считывается.

Если после отладки отдельно запускать только что собранный .exe файл, считывание происходит и всё работает корректно.

Пожалуйста подскажите - почему процесс отладки игнорирует данную команду, и что нужно настроить (и где), что бы при отладке можно было бы работать с данными, читаемыми из файла?

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - рабочий каталог.

Comment: СПАСИБО! :) это точно было оно! как-то странно, что в проекте есть две папки Debug, и по умолчанию стоит та, которая похоронена как матрёшка в одноимённой папке проекта :), отдельно от .exe файла

Comment: ^_^ благодарю, Abyx

Answer (score 1):

Огромное спасибо kff и Abyx. 
Проблема действительно оказалась в рабочем каталоге. 
По умолчанию, Visual Studio 2013 выбрал другой каталог для отладки.
Естественно, в том каталоге файла нет. 
Замена каталога на нужный позволила решить проблему.
(рождается следующий вопрос - :) зачем они это делают?)

На картинке видно что в папке с проектом **IntS_NN_LR1** есть папка Debug и ещё одна папка с одноимённым названием проекта, в которой есть ещё одна папка Debug,
на которую, как на $project стоял линк в настройках рабочего каталога.

[image: Матрёшка от VC2013]1]]